# How to check if a child is next to a certain child in javascript

Tags: javascript, parent-child

I'm making a simple puzzle slider game with javascript and I'm a bit stumped. Is there a way to check to see if a child is next to another specific child? Would I just have to track the x & y location of the specific child to do that or is there an easier way?

Here is the puzzle for context. The specific child in question is the white tile in the bottom right corner.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jqGWgw

HTML

```
<body>
    <h1>Fifteen Puzzle</h1>

    <p>
        The goal of the fifteen puzzle is to un-jumble its fifteen squares
        by repeatedly making moves that slide squares into the empty space.
        How quickly can you solve it?
    </p>

    <div id="puzzlearea">
    <!--
        this area holds the actual fifteen puzzle pieces
        add to it as you need to
    -->
    </div>

    <p id="controls">
        <button id="shufflebutton">Shuffle</button>
    </p>

    <div id="output"></div>



</body>
```

CSS

```
    #puzzlearea{
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    background-color:white;
}

.tiles{
    width:90px;
    height:90px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:black;
    color:aliceblue;
    text-shadow: -1.5px 0 black, 0 1.5px black, 1.5px 0 black, 0 -1.5px black;
    border-width: 5px;
    float:left;
}

#tile0{
    background:url(background.jpg);
    background-position: 0px 0px;
}
#tile1{
    background:url(background.jpg);
    background-position: -100px 0px;}
#tile2{
    background:url(background.jpg);
    background-position: -200px 0px;}
#tile3{
    background:url(background.jpg);
    background-position: -300px 0px;}
#tile4{
    background:url(background.jpg);
    background-position: 0px -100px;}
#tile5{
    background:url(background.jpg);
    background-position: -100px -100px;}
#tile6{
    background:url(background.jpg);
    background-position: -200px -100px;}
#tile7{
    background:url(background.jpg);
    background-position: -300px -100px;}
#tile8{
    background:url(background.jpg);
    background-position: 0px -200px;}
#tile9{
    background:url(background.jpg);
    background-position: -100px -200px;}
#tile10{
    background:url(background.jpg);
    background-position: -200px -200px;}
#tile11{
    background:url(background.jpg);
    background-position: -300px -200px;}
#tile12{
    background:url(background.jpg);
    background-position: 0px -300px;}
#tile13{
    background:url(background.jpg);
    background-position: -100px -300px;}
#tile14{
    background:url(background.jpg);
    background-position: -200px -300px;}
.tiles:last-child{
    background-color: white;
    border: none;
}
```

Javascript

```
    window.onload = function(){
        createTiles()
    }

function createTiles() {
    var count = 16;
        for(var i=0; i<count; i++){
            if(i<15){
                var newTile = document.createElement('div');
            newTile.id = "tile"+i;
            newTile.className = 'tiles';
            newTile.innerHTML=i;
            document.getElementById('puzzlearea').appendChild(newTile);
            }
            else{
            var newTile = document.createElement('div');
            newTile.id = "tile"+i;
            newTile.className = 'tiles';
            document.getElementById('puzzlearea').appendChild(newTile);
            }
    }


}
```

Comment: off-topic: The CSS part seems unrelated to your question, please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Your logic/state should not rely on DOM, rather the other way round.

Comment: If i understand your need, you only need to check x,y position or position in grid ?  This is only about some math, you know. (Precise your needs and we will try to help you, even with math things, this can be hard)